# Unsupported get request using Ads Facebook SDK for PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to access ads campaigns related data (such as country, cpm, spent ...)  using Facebook [php-ads-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk)

The Facebook user is already added as admin in Facebook Bussiness Manager.

The first thing I do is get the access token given the *app_secret* and *app_id* of the user:

```
public function getAccessToken()
{
    try {
        $response = $this->client->get(
            $this->accessTokenUrl, [
            'query' => [
                'client_id' => $this->appId,
                'client_secret' => $this->appSecret,
                'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            ],
            'stream' => true
        ]);
    } catch(RequestException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $body = $response->getBody();
    $contents = $body->getContents();

    $contentsArray = explode('=', $contents);

    return $contentsArray[1];
}
```

It comes in the form:

> access_token=xxxxxx

That's why I have to make an explode.

Once I got the access token, I authenticate in the Api:

```
Api::init($this->appId, $this->appSecret, $this->accessToken);
$api = Api::instance();
```

Finally I try to get some data using the Bussiness Manager account id:

```
$account = new AdAccount($this->accountId);
$test = $account->getAdCampaigns();
```

But I get the following error message:

> [FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException]
>   Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested in the first comment by Paul Bain, I changed these lines:

```
$account = new AdAccount($this->accountId);
$test = $account->getAdCampaigns();
```

For these ones:

```
$account = new AdAccount('act_' . $this->accountId);
$test = $account->getAdCampaigns();
```

And now I get a different error message:

> (#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action

I don't know why I don't have sufficient permissions, since as I said before the user is added as admin in Facebook Bussiness Manager.

Also in the facebook user profile, under settings/advanced, the Facebook Bussiness Manager account id is added in 'Authorized Ad Account IDs'

The app is approved for Basic access level.

Comment: you've kindof vandalized your own question here as this is actually a different question that has been answered many times. Have you requested the ads_management permission for the access token you have? Have you listed the adaccount you are using under your app settings?

Comment: You're right, it is a different question now. The problem was fixed requesting the ads_management permission. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix the ID of the adaccount you are trying to access with `act_` otherwise this will not work.

For example, if you do the following, you will see that the IDs of all the adaccounts are prefixed this way in the API response:

```
use FacebookAds\Object\AdUser;
$user = new AdUser('me');
$accounts = $user->getAdAccounts(array('name'));
foreach($accounts as $act) {
  echo $account->id." - ".$account->name.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Updated the post with your answer.

Comment: Hey @paulbain do you know if what will I use if I just want to get the ads like, `ads_archive?ad_reached_countries=US,CN&search_terms=bags ` i don't know which to use when using the Facebook SDK. please help